# Response format to UID FETCH 14105,14108 (BODY.PEEK[1]<0.1048576>)

Tags: smtp, imap

We are building own IMAP server (a bridge to our own system).
I have mobile outlook sending FETCH request as below, we send response back but apparently nothing happens eg. these messages are not appearing.

What the correct response for these FETCHES?

```html
C (th 1 #6044116): A7 UID FETCH 14105,14108 (BODY.PEEK[1]<0.1048576>)
S (th 1 #35320229): * 355 FETCH (UID 14105 BODY[1]<0> {11}
hello??

)
S (th 1 #35320229): * 356 FETCH (UID 14108 BODY[1]<0> {13}
anybody??

)
S (th 1 #35320229): A7 OK UID FETCH
```

Thank you
Dimi

Comment: What did you tell it the body structure for those messages was?